# why do the commented code also work?

Tags: html, google-chrome, comments

I'm just surprised today, while testing my site I found something interesting on chrome browser:

`<jdoc:include type="head" />` which results joomla features links and meta, etc like this:

```
<base href="" />
    <meta />
    ......
```

But even after commenting the code like this:

```
<!---<jdoc:include type="head" />--->
```

Results while inspecting:

```
<!---
<base href="" />
<meta />
......

--->
```

Why is this not showing just `<!---<jdoc:include type="head" />--->`

---

Please note: `<jdoc:include type="head" />` is joomla framework feature...

Comment: Presumably because joomla doesn't care if something's in an HTML comment when it does whatever `<jdoc...` does. Why should it? To the framework, the template is just text. (This almost certainly has nothing to do with Chrome, but is happening on the server...)

Comment: Should the comment not be 2 hyphens rather than three

Comment: Is that because the priority problem? Like `<!--<?= $_POST['me']; ?>-->` will still work, whatever you does to it, it should not be able to display that code.

Answer (score 1):

`<jdoc... />` is processed on the **server side (on Joomla's servers)**. This means that it will ignore the comment marks and process everything that makes sense to it because **HTML comment marks are processed on the client side, not the server side**. After it has been processed by the server, it sends the processed info with the comment marks to the client side and then the **client side filters it out as a comment**. This is why you are getting all the new code like `<base href="" />` when it is a comment.

Hope I helped!